# Ajuda em programação visual basic

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub GridWithLoop()

    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim sum2 As Integer = 0
    Dim allrow As DataGridViewRow
    Dim band As DataGridViewBand

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        'sum = sum + DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value'
        allrow = DataGridView2.Rows(i)

        If allrow.Cells(1).Value.ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
            'Nothing happen'
        Else
            band = DataGridView2.Rows(i)
            band.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, dá erro quando tento colocar o row como invisível, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olá seja bem vindo ao Sopt , você pode [adicionar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/125265/edit) a mensagem de erro que foi exibida na sua pergunta ?

Answer (score 1):

Por acaso seu DataGridView permite a inserção de linhas? Você não pode ocultar a linha que fica pendente para inserção de dados novos. Teste a propriedade `allrow.IsNewRow` para evitar isso. 
Não entendi por que você está usando o objeto DataGridViewBand para esse fim?
Tente isto:

```
Private Sub GridWithLoop()

    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim sum2 As Integer = 0
    Dim allrow As DataGridViewRow
    Dim band As DataGridViewBand

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        'sum = sum + DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value'
        allrow = DataGridView2.Rows(i)

        If allrow.Cells(1).Value.ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
            'Nothing happen'
        ElseIf Not allrow.IsNewRow Then
            allrow.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```